# Handling collaboration requests from the authors of double-blind reviewed papers (after submitting the review)

Tags: peer-review, ethics, collaboration, anonymity

(I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I was not able to find any similar case on AcademiaSE)

I am finding myself in a very odd and unpleasant situation. The subject is "ethical" peer review in Computer Science.

I am a sub-reviewer of a conference. As such, I was assigned some papers to review (in double-blind format); however, for the papers I am assigned, I am able to see who the other reviewers are, and also their reviews on these papers. As a sub-reviewer, my name does not appear on the listed TPC of the conference.

Among the papers I am assigned, there is Paper A. I reviewed this paper and I liked it, albeit it had some flaws. After submitting my review, I was able to read the other reviewers' remarks - some were positive, some negative. My (positive) comments allowed the paper to pass the first round of review.

Now the problem: I received an email from a Researcher X *who I did not know*, asking a collaboration proposal; **the email had Paper A in the attachment**. Apparently, Researcher X found it relevant to include a proof that they're working on something to corroborate the collaboration request. I would be very willing to collaborate with X, as I consider their research group to be strong.

You can easily understand my awkward situation: *what to do?*

Things to take in mind:

- My review has already been submitted *and* evaluated. Hence, I cannot turn down the review-request.
- I can turn down the collaboration request, but I would lose a significant opportunity for my academic career.
- Even if I warn the TPC of the conference to "retract" my review, I was still able to see the reviews of the other reviewers (as well as their names).
- Moreover, my review has already had an impact on the future of the paper.
- My name did not appear on the TPC list, meaning that Researcher X acted in good faith.

Comment: You have given the review. Unless you have to re-review, there is no problem here. Your decision was given *before* you had a conflict-of-interest. If there is a second round of reviews, you can ask the organizer to recuse yourself for future rounds, as you just have been contacted and would like to consider following up.

Comment: @Buffy and CaptainEmacs are right. There's no ethical problem here at all. But +1 on the question for the caution that led you to ask.

Comment: Thanks for reassuring me!

Comment: It sounds like researcher X isn't even related to paper A, did I miss something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Given the timeline there is no ethical concern. You don't need to retract your review and you can agree to collaborate.

However, you should decline to review paper A if it goes to a next round. And in the short term you should refrain from telling the authors of your review. I don't see an issue in telling them later, after a final decision is made by others.

You might want to inform the program chair of the situation, giving the timeline. I doubt that they would have any complaint nor any reason to act.

Given what you say, the events seem to be entirely independent. Serendipity happens.

Comment: I should have read your answer before giving my comment. All said here. +1

Comment: Thanks! Your suggestion is spot-on! I'll accept the answer tomorrow unless some contrasting opinions arise :)